# Do I need to test the domain services in Domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am developing a console application using domain driven design, i tried to keep the domain logic as much as possible into domain entities, but some how, some logic leaked into domain services, so now, do i need to test the domain services, if yes how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First always make sure that your domain services are stateless.

The usual roles of domain services is stuff like validation and persistence. In those cases simply create mocks/stubs/dummies of infrastructure services that they use, pass them in, inside a unit test and assert certain behavior on those mocks. Business as usual. Sometimes the domain services need entities. Mock and pass those in as well. Assert as usual.

Inevitably someone will chime in with the venerable statement of: "but domain services aren't about persistence". If a domain service deals/uses some persistence mechanism (repository/gateway) to accomplish some responsibility, then it's perfectly reasonable 'english' to state 'its usual role is stuff like persistence'.

With that out of the way. DDD does not make decoupling goals. Good DDD is allowing ALL your business logic to happen in the domain. Making Domain Services stateless accomplishes that. Like VO It makes DS safe to pass around from outside layers. Keeping the API of DS consistent with your ubiquitous language insures they remain as a coherent unit of organization within your domain.

*"But DS are not about persistence"..* only if the ubiquitous language is not, and it often isn't, so the DS API shouldn't in those cases reflect a persistence mechanism. But it sure as hell can have internal methods that use a hell lot of persistence, and you will need to use mocks/stubs/dummies to get at those suckers in unit tests. Domain Services aren't some architectural scaffolding for keeping your layers separate. They are a unit of organization for higher level domain logic.

Comment: What do you mean by "stateless" considering domain services.

Comment: A stateless service is simply a module that does not track information from call to call. For example, a service class that changes instance variables between calls is NOT stateless. 

The service may have instance variables that get set during construction time - such as infrastructure services - but may not have methods that would change data. Everything it needs should just be passed in during method evocation.

Comment: I feel like i understood what you explained, Can you please provide an example for the same? @SephVelut

Comment: @SephVelut Domain Services are not about persistence. The Domain shouldn't know about persistence. Validation... depends what you mean, but Application Services is mostly where it happens.

Comment: @guillaume31 Wrong. Implementations of domain services are usually using repositories, gateways or some other infrastructure service. The Interface model of domain services are still kept ignorant of the infrastructure. Furthermore, the question is about testing, and you test implementations, so yes your tests will likely have to mock out some infrastructure stuff to get at the domain services.

Comment: You stated that "the usual role of a Domain Service is stuff like validation or persistence", which is different from saying "it is using a Repository". You might use a Repo inside a Domain Service (although in my experience it's cleaner to let the Application Service do it and pass entities to the DS), but in no way is a DS in charge of persistence.

Comment: Domain Services contain **domain logic** that doesn't fit in any Entity. Textbook example : `FundsTransferService.Transfer(Account a, Account b)`. [Application Services are not Domain Services](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

Comment: @guillaume31 I think you're just frivolously coming up with issues against my particular wording. In `Implementing Domain-Driven Design`, Vaughn Vernon often uses identity access [services](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/ForumIdentityService.java) as examples of domain services. These services are only concerned with persistence semantics. They access persistence and retrieve id's for validation and for later persistence. The difference in wording you are pointing out is a bit mundane.

Comment: You mentioned you would just pass entities into your domain services from the application layer? Why? This defeats the consistency boundary that aggregates are supposed to protect. Having application services hold references to mutable entities from the domain is a no-no in DDD. Application services are not meant to be the clients of domain services, the API of the domain services should be consumed by aggregates. You're also leaking volatile implementation details (da **domain logic**) out of the domain service and into an application service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77546/discussion-between-sephvelut-and-guillaume31).

Comment: Domain Services are not about persistence or validation, they are about business logic. If DS were about persistence or validation, you should not need DS...

Comment: Stop saying Domain Services are about validation and persistence! Just stop, please. Member functions give an object its semantics. If a domain service deals with persistence to accomplish some responsibility, then it's perfectly reasonable 'english' to state 'its usual role is stuff like persistence'. "but but, domain interfaces should be persistence ignorant".. That's nice, your implementation probably won't, and that is what you're testing. But feel free meander about the perceived linguistic discrepancy until the cows come home.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if they contain logic, they have to be tested.

If the service was properly decoupled, it should be possible to test it with unit tests and dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

[Domain Services](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) are all about domain logic, so they should definitely be tested.

It's all the more simple to do since they have **very few dependencies**, and especially usually no coupling to infrastructure classes doing slow I/O stuff.

The domain layer is at the center of your application and isn't tightly coupled to any other layer, most calls will stay inside its boundaries. If Domain Services want to communicate to the outside world, they'll often use events. Therefore, you should need little to no mocks or stubs when testing them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework you use. Using C# and depending on project complexity, I would take advantage on DI and factories (if any), or implement some functional tests (retrospectively) with SpecFlow and Moq, given interface contracts you should have written when implementing your domain services. The starting point would consist in installing SpecFlow, and then, you should create a dedicated test project...

http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/